# Angular 2-final -- Getting started with Karma & Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular 2.0.0 application. But I want to test it. Now, I'm completely new to the Karma and Jasmine frameworks.

It just seems like there are currently no good guides on how to test the final version of Angular 2.0.0 with Karma and Jasmine.

Now I got to the part where I have working Jasmine tests. But I just can't seem to get Karma working. It keeps saying `0/0 ERROR`.

So I was wondering. Does anybody have a working example of the basic setup of the `karma.conf.js` file and the `karma-test-shim.js` file regarding Angular2.0.0?

[Issue getting Karma 1.1.0 and Angular 2 tests working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055676/issue-getting-karma-1-1-0-and-angular-2-tests-working) This might seem the same kind of question, althought the answer is for `angular-2.0.0-rc1` and I'm looking for a final version.

Comment: Angular updated their docs [testing section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) recently. It's pretty loaded compared to before.

Comment: Yes but they just say 'create the setup files' and do not provide any content of these files. They expect you to know it.

Comment: I think there's a link of the example setup files they use. The link is to the [quickstart project](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had that `0/0 Error` before. It's caused by the `karma.conf.js` set up not actually pointing to any test files.

In my project, my structure looks like this:

```
.
+-- src
|   +-- app
|   |   +-- *.spec.ts
|   +-- config
|   |   +-- karma.conf.js
|   |   +-- test.ts
```

The karma.conf.js has a `files: [{pattern: './test.ts'}]` block.

Then, in your test.ts file, you make sure the expression matches your location for your tests:

```
 // Then we find all the tests.
.then(() => require.context('../', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
```

So, you're looking to make sure that require.context() matches where your tests will be and the notation you've used to signify them. Hope this helps!

Comment: you were right, changed the regex to my needs. Executing tests now.